# Vote up awarded less than 10 rep

Tags: support, reputation, upvotes

This might be a super silly question, but i can't seem to find an answer. I got a vote up on one of my answer and i got 6 rep instead or 10. Is that normal? If so why did it happen?

Update: I checked and apprently i have lost `4` rep due to a question that i have not answered and neither asked, [**link**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197511/utf-8-error-with-verbments)

[image]

Comment: Given that that is about a question on tex.se, why didn't you ask it on meta.tex.se?

Comment: i just saw that i lost 4 rep due to this plus i didn't lose rep on tex. I lost rep on StackOverflow

Comment: Could you include a screen shot of your [reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3669940/xgeorgekx?tab=reputation&sort=time) that shows this -4?

Comment: added the screenshot

Comment: I assume you had two suggested edits to "How to highlight..." that were approved?

Comment: oh well. I don't know. But 2 edits? Doesn't make much sense. I mean. why would i edit twice.

Comment: Why are questions like these downvoted? it's just clarifying stuff

Comment: @Coffee who knows..

Comment: @Coffee not a down voter here, but many times there are 'I lost rep! I want it back!' type posts on meta that people tire of.  Even without that tone in this question, one could easily read it that way if you've seen them enough.  The down vote would then be an indication of "ug, another one? down vote - I don't want to see it."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25452856/revisions was migrated to TeX.SE (anyone can access the edit history, despite it being deleted because it was migrated).

You had two suggested edits (each worth +2) at revision 2 and revision 4.

When a question is migrated, the reputation earned from up votes goes to the new site. Reputation gained from edits to posts in that question and any lost from down votes are erased as part of the migration.

Thus, when this was migrated, you lost the reputation from the edits as the edit history isn't moved with it.

Eventually one of the roomba scripts comes along (this case it was the 30 day one) and deletes migrated questions from the origin site so they don't clutter things up.  You lost the rep as part of that deletion.